# MySQL select clients by longest tenure greater than 30 days old

Tags: mysql

I have a view called acquity_fields that I created with the following columns:
meta_id; post_id; meta_key; meta_value (meta_id is unique)

The meta_value column contains the fields I need to query so that I can find the length of time a client has been coming to a clinic. [see the set up for meta_values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzQwq.png)

Each client gets added with a unix time to reflect their appointment, so they may be listed multiple times.
Here is what I have tried so far as a start, just to see if I can grab records that are over 30 days old:

```
SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(`meta_value`)
    FROM acquity_fields 
    WHERE meta_key = 'wpcf-acquity-last-name' AND meta_key = 'wpcf-acquity-date' > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

But this returns 'MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).'

I know that when I can get these results for over 30 days, I will have to find the oldest record for each last name then display them. (Eventually I will use the results in a pie chart with %s for time frames (e.g. <3 mo; 3-6 mo; 6 mo- 1 yr; > 1 yr)

Thanks

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And, while meta_id is PRIMARY, presumably (post_id,meta_key) is UNIQUE